# How does GatsbyJS infer GraphQL datatypes?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

`GraphQL Error Field "tags" must not have a selection since type "[String]" has no subfields.`

I'm working on a GatsbyJS repo. According to the [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/querying-with-graphql/), GatsbyJS automatically infers the schema from my markdown files, which implicitly define the type with lines such as `tags: ["sayings", "wisdom"]`. Surely, GatsbyJS should infer the type to be an array, a list, or something like that. Why does GatsbyJS infer the type to be a String instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your development server is running, you can access the GraphiQL interface for it at `http://localhost:8000/___graphql`. Graph*i*QL is an IDE that can not only lets you write and run queries against your GraphQL server, but also provides a way to view your schema, including the type for each available field. Please see [the docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/introducing-graphiql/) for more info. It includes syntax highlighting, so I would highly recommend it when composing your queries.

The error you are seeing indicates that the field `tags` is of the type `[String]`. The brackets here indicate a `List` (or array) of the type `String`. `String`, `Int`, `Float`, `Boolean` and `ID` are all built-in scalar types. Fields that have a scalar type (or an enum) are considered "lead nodes", and as such, they cannot have a field selection themselves. In other words,

```
tags {}
```

is not valid syntax. It has to be just

```
tags
```

That is why you are seeing the above error. As it states, the type `[String]` has no subfields. If hypothetically the type returned by the `tags` field was an object type, or a list of one, then you would have to specify what fields to return.

You might find it helpful to review GraphQL concepts in more details. [This tutorial](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/) would be a good starting point, and there's always the [specification itself](https://facebook.github.io/graphql/).

Comment: Ah! I was confusing the elements of the array to be subfields, which of course they are not. Thank you!